# Django - operate on db or on data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django with PostreSQL to retrieve some data via DRF and use this JSON in React.

The data that gets called is already filter with

```
models.objects.filter(owner=request.user, date=last_month)
```

All of the fields in the dataset are required, thus no further filtering is required and there is no overhead data.

Now I want to split the data of `last_month` into groups per days.

The question is should I:

1. Make different ORM calls for everyday
2. Make ORM call as in the example above and iterate through it in
   django with pandas
3. Make an call as in the example above and iterate through
   it in react

Which is the most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better to use filter and query once by passing group by and then iterate through it, one call and all data is there in the cache

Comment: thanks I thought so. and is pandas the right library for that?